# in Bixby input-view how do I match multiple concepts in a multicheckbox select

Tags: bixby

I am asking the user to fill in a form that includes a multiple checkbox form element to provide true/false values for multiple concepts.

So I have a view like this:

```
input-view{
    match:PremiumContent

  message("Which of the following features do you need?")

    render{
    form{
      elements{
        checkbox{
          id(premiumcontent)
          type (PremiumContent)
          primary-text (Yes, I want to provide premium content.)
          secondary-text (We recommend providing a free tier.)
          value(true)
        }
        checkbox{
          id(searchabletext)
          type (SearchableText)
          primary-text (Yes, I want to provide searchable text.)
          secondary-text (Passages of one to three paragraphs work well.)
          value(true)
        }
        checkbox{
          id(twittersearch)
          type (TwitterSearch)
          primary-text (Yes, I want to pull permissioned Twitter results into my capsule.)
          secondary-text (AltBrains supports the full twitter search syntax.)
          value(true)
        }
         checkbox{
          id(carousel)
          type (Carousel)
          primary-text (Yes, I want an image gallery.)
          secondary-text (JPG or PNG at least 720 x 480.)
          value(true)
        }
      }
          on-submit{
        goal:PremiumContent
        value:viv.core.FormElement(premiumcontent)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that would replace four individual view pages for PremiumContent, SearchableText, Carousel, and TwitterSearch. But I don't know how to construct the Match query.    How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I would try making a parent `Boolean` and then have each of `PremiumContent`, `SearchableText`, `TwitterSearch`, and `Carousel` either take the role of that parent boolean or extend it. You would then use that parent boolean in the match pattern.

So something like:

```
boolean (Parent) {}
```

and either

```
boolean (PremiumContent) {
  role-of (Parent)
}
boolean (SearchableText) {
  role-of (Parent)
}
...
```

or

```
boolean (PremiumContent) {
  extends (Parent)
}
boolean (SearchableText) {
  extends (Parent)
}
...
```

and then your match pattern would be:

```
match: Parent
```

and your `on-submit` should be something like:

```
on-submit {
  goal: Parent
  value-set: Parent {
    viv.core.FormElement (premiumcontent)
    viv.core.FormElement (searchabletext)
    ...
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could make a structure with the four different boolean properties and then use the structure in the match pattern. So something like:

```
structure (Thing) {
  property (premiumContent) {
    type (PremiumContent)
  }
  ...
}
```

And then your match pattern would be:

```
match: Thing
```

and then your `on-submit` would be:

```
on-submit {
  goal: Thing
  value: Thing {
    premiumContent: viv.core.FormElement (premiumcontent)
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a structure that contains all of the boolean as property.

Use the following as an example. Read more [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/input-view.render.form.elements.checkbox)

```
input-view {
  match: Person (this)

  message {
    template (Fill in your information)
  }

  render {
    form {
      // the intent that will be used when the form is submitted
      on-submit {
        goal: viv.tutorial.Person
        value: viv.tutorial.Person {
          wineClubJoined: viv.core.FormElement(wineclub)
          beerClubJoined: viv.core.FormElement(beerclub)
        }
      }
      elements {
        checkbox {
          id ("wineclub")
          type (WineClubJoined)
          primary-text (Join the wine club)
          secondary-text (We will invite you to our monthly wine events)
          value ("#{raw(this.wineClubJoined)}")
        }
        checkbox {
          id ("beerclub")
          type (BeerClubJoined)
          primary-text (Join the beer club)
          secondary-text (We will invite you to our monthly beer events)
          value ("#{raw(this.beerClubJoined)}")
        }

      }
    }
  }
```